# Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property (with realexpayments)

Tags: php

I got this error on line 38:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\CardType::$cardType

Line 38:

```
->addType(CardType::$cardType)
```

My code:

```
$numCard = isset($_POST['numCard']);
$expCardMont = isset($_POST['expCardMont']);
$expCardYear = isset($_POST['expCardYear']);
$expDate = $expCardMont.$expCardYear;
$cvnCard = isset($_POST['cvnCard']);
$titulaireNameCard = isset($_POST['titulaireNameCard']);
$cardType = isset($_POST['cardType']);
$total = isset($_POST['total']);

// var_dump($numCard);

require_once ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\Card;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\CardType;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\PresenceIndicator;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\payment\AutoSettle;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\payment\AutoSettleFlag;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\payment\PaymentRequest;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\payment\PaymentResponse;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\payment\PaymentType;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain\payment\Mpi;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\RealexClient;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\RealexException;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\RealexServerException;
use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\http\HttpConfiguration;

$card = (new Card())
->addType(CardType::$cardType)
->addNumber($numCard)
->addExpiryDate($expDate)
->addCvn($cvnCard)
->addCvnPresenceIndicator(PresenceIndicator::CVN_PRESENT)
->addCardHolderName($titulaireNameCard);

$request = (new PaymentRequest())
->addType(PaymentType::AUTH)
->addMerchantId("xxx")
->addAccount("internet")
->addAmount($total)
->addCurrency("CAD")
->addCard($card)
->addAutoSettle((new AutoSettle())->addFlag(AutoSettleFlag::TRUE));

$httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
$httpConfiguration->setEndpoint("https://test.realexpayments.com/epage-remote.cgi");
$client = new RealexClient("xxx", $httpConfiguration);

try {
$paymentResponse = $client->send($request);
echo $paymentResponse->getResult(); // '00' == success
//get the details required for Transaction Management requests
$paymentsReference = $paymentResponse->getPaymentsReference();
$authCode = $paymentResponse->getAuthCode();
$orderId = $paymentResponse->getorderId();

return $paymentResponse->getMessage();
}
catch ( RealexServerException $e ) {
return $e->getMessage();
}
catch ( RealexException $e ) {
return $e->getMessage();
}
```

An idea of ​​why? Thank you!

CardType code if you needed it:

```
<?php


namespace com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\domain;


use com\realexpayments\remote\sdk\EnumBase;


/**
 * Enumeration representing card types.
 */
class CardType extends EnumBase {

    const __default = self::VISA;

    const VISA = "VISA";
    const MASTERCARD = "MC";
    const AMEX = "AMEX";
    const CB = "CB";
    const DINERS = "DINERS";
    const JCB = "JCB";

    /**
     * @var string The card type
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @param string $type
     */
    public function __construct( $type ) {
        parent::__construct( $type );

        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the card type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Well, there is no `$cardType` (static) property declared within the `CardType` class. The error looks quite clear :) Also lines such as `$numCard = isset($_POST['numCard']);` look very suspicious...

Comment: @Jeto Not for me x) How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: To be completely honest? Taking a basic PHP course/tutorial would seem like a necessary step. Not saying this to be mean at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code states

```
$cardType = isset($_POST['cardType']);
```

Which sets `$cardType` to a boolean so not only is `CardType::$cardType` not valid, it doesn't make technical sense.

What you might have wanted was

```
$cardType = isset($_POST['cardType']) ? $_POST['cardType'] : null;
```

and then

```
->addType(new CardType($cardType))
```

Overall, configuring better input validation would help you significantly because `$cardType` being `null` would probably also throw errors.

Comment: `CardType::$cardType` still doesn't exist though.

Comment: Yep, dove further into the code and it looks like what they want might be `->addType(new CardType($cardType))`